# Removing characters from a string

Tags: java, android, string, character

I have an app in which I parse a .txt file from a URL and spit out the string to the user. I want to remove the first 16 characters of the string. How can I do this?

EDIT- I want to remove 16 characters from the data I receive from my http call.

```
public void onClick(View src) {
        switch(src.getId()) {
        case R.id.buttonRetrieveMetar:


            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)   
getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(EditTextAirportCode.getWindowToken(), 0);


            textDisplayMetar.setText ("");


            airportcode = EditTextAirportCode.getText().toString();
            url = urlmetar + airportcode + ".TXT";

            //Added 06-27-11 METAR code
            textDisplayMetar.setText ("");

            try {
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                // Execute HTTP Get Request
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
                content = response.getEntity().getContent();
                BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new     
InputStreamReader(content));
                StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                    total.append(line);
                } 
                textDisplayMetar.append("\n" + total + "\n");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                //handle the exception !
            }


   break;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't modify the string itself, but you can create a substring easily enough:

```
line = line.substring(16);
```

The single-parameter overload of `substring` takes the *whole* of the rest of the string after the given start index. The two-parameter overload starts at an index specified by the first argument, and ends at an index specified by the second argument (exclusive). So to get the first three characters after "skipping" the first 16, you'd use:

```
line = line.substring(16, 19);
```

Note that you don't have to assign back to the same variable - but you need to understand that it doesn't affect the string *object* that you call it on. So:

```
String original = "hello world";
String secondPart = original.substring(6);

System.out.println(original); // Still prints hello world
System.out.println(secondPart); // Prints world
```

EDIT: If you want to remove the first 16 characters of the whole file, you want:

```
textDisplayMetar.append("\n" + total.toString().substring(16) + "\n");
```

If you want that on a *per-line* basis, you want:

```
while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
    total.append(line.substring(16));
}
```

Note that both of these may require extra validation - if you call `substring(16)` on a string with less than 16 characters, it will throw an exception.

Comment: That makes sense, unfortunately I still need a little bit of help putting it into context. I will edit my original post. I want to remove 16 characters off of what I parse from the url.

Comment: @Slicekick: From each line, or from just the start of the whole file? I've included an edit for the latter case, and will include the former case as well.

Comment: That's done it! Thanks for explaining it as well, really appreciate it. I hope to work at Google one day.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String newString = oldString.substring(16);
```